How to access files of Samsung M21 stuck in boot loop
I have a Samsung M21 that apparently has become stuck in a boot loop (thought actually I do not see whether it is "looping" or simply stuck in the logo screen). This could be related to a lack of space in the internal memory since it was quite full and the symptoms it seems to match some similar posts, but I would be surprised as I never got the typical warning for lack of space.
The only thing I want is to access the files that are in the internal memory, mainly photos/videos. I don't care whether I need to rip it apart to extract the internal sd card or memory chip, but since the disassembly videos I've found apparently show that the memory chip is soldered (though not sure about that), I am trying less invasive solutions.
First thing I tried was entering in the recovery menu. Wiped the cache partition but did not solve the boot problem. Then I tried selecting the option Apply update from ADB to see whether this would allow me to enter the filesystem via ADB, but apparently this does not grant me permission: all commands like adb backup or adb shell or adb pull resulted in similar errors like adb: unable to connect for backup: closed, error: closed, or adb: error: connect failed: closed. This I did it from an Ubuntu 22.04 system.
*Edit: adb devices -l gives
[edited serial no.]        sideload usb:3-3 product:m21nsxx model:SM_M215F device:m21 transport_id:4
After reading more, I am wondering whether the "Download mode" and this Odin program, which is the first time I hear about, would allow me to access the files. Has anyone any suggestion or experience with this kind of issue?
A second problem is that every time I try, entering in recovery mode becomes a complete pain. Since forcing the reboot with Power + VolDown very quickly makes the logo screen appear again, there is barely any time to enter the Power + VolUp combination. The times I made, I am not sure of whether it was pure chance. Is there any ideal procedure for this?
Finally, in case that I must dismantle the thing, does anyone know which kind of adapter or material must I find for getting the memory chip and connecting it to a computer?
Thanks in advance!

"Apply update from ADB" is an alias for "ad sideload" a special adb mode which only allows to install OTA system updates. Extracting the flash memory chip (if it is a separate chip at all) is a waste of time as the data is encrypted in a way that it can not be decrypted outside of the device. If the phone uses File Based Encryption and the root cause is lack of free space o user data partition it may be theoretically possible to delete some files after directly accessing the flash chip, but (de)soldering flash chips is AFAIK extremely difficult and requires expensive hardware.

Thanks! AFAIK the files are not encrypted, the method I used for the last backup was accessing from Ubuntu via USB cable, locating the mounting point, and then rsync the whole filesystem. However the physical option is indeed the very last resort. I am still astonished that there is apparently no way to simply mount it and access it from the external device.

An Android device released in 2020 is always encrypted by default even if you have not (tried) to enable encryption and have no lock screen PIN/password/pattern.

Then I guess that whatever I do must be thorough the device' system. I understand that the options "Apply update from ADB" and "Apply update from SD" can be used for updating the OS without losing the data in the phone (i.e. they are regular updates and NOT factory resets). Is there an option that I can use that to restore the system? Maybe trying a lighter OS version would be useful if the problem is lack of free space?

If you would install an OS without proper Samsung signature (assuming that you already have enabled OEM unlock in developer settings while the phone was still usable) this will  trigger a factory reset erasing all your data without any chance to recover a single byte. I have read that some Samsung signed "backdoor-images" were leaked some years ago, but I am not sure if they work in general and for your phone in detail. Never used them.

It seems that I am quite screwed then. The last thing I am looking is these programas like Droidkit and similar, that claim they can recover data from bricked phones, or repair the system etc. However it seems they require a subscription, and I am not sure they are legit. Plus, I suspect they would not work if the system is already rooted. Some experiences?
Also: the Android version is 10/QP1A.190711.020, FWIW.
